# How do I reinitialize my jQuery calls after calling .html() to replace content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a page with various jQuery calls on initial load (select2, 'onclick' etc.).  It's a remote JS form in my Rails app.  If the submit fails I have the page reload the form again for the user to correct validations etc.

The issue is all the intial jQuery calls do not persist on the reloaded content (via a `.html()` call).

I have found a few posts like this:

[Reinitialize jQuery after AJAX call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517592/reinitialize-jquery-after-ajax-call)

I have fixed most of the original calls like this which now works fine:

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'input.item_quantity', function(event){
    my code etc...
});
```

I have others like this which I can't seem to resolve:

```
$(function() {
  $('[data-behavior="select2-parent"]').select2({
    ajax: {
      url: 'myurl',
      dataType: 'json'
    }
  });
});
```

These are all the calls on the document loading and not due to user interaction.  I can make these load when the user clicks on the inputs but there is a slight delay between the user click and the select2 kicking in.  I need this to persist even when I reload content via the `.html()`.

Calling this direct after reload in the console works:

```
$('[data-behavior="select2-parent"]').select2();
```

I added this to the code where my `.html()` is called but the select2 does not initialize and no console errors.

How have these select2 call bind to the initial elements and ones added afterwards?  I suspect I may be missing something small or obvious here.

**EDIT:** The URL in the select2 AJAX config is also dynamic based on other form input values.

Comment: Hi Dan, did my answer end up working for you?

Comment: It was close enough to accept.  I my case I just needed to call `select2` again to re-initialize.

Comment: Glad you got it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to simply have to re-initialize the select2 elements. Your second call after the `.html()` is not working because the `.select2()` call is expecting your configuration passed to it like you did when you first initialized. It has no prior knowledge of your configuration, especially if you are replacing the entire `.html()`. I would recommend saving your configuration to a variable that can be re-used.

```
const select2Config = {
  ajax: {
    url: 'myurl',
    dataType: 'json'
  }
};

$(function() {
  $('[data-behavior="select2-parent"]').select2(select2Config);
});
```

Then you can call it again after your `.html()` call. You may have to [destroy the `select2` control](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/methods#destroying-the-select2-control) before re-initializing, which will unbind all of the events to it. If you have a dynamic URL, you can simply override that part of the config to minimize code duplication:

```
/* ... .html() call here ... */

// get new dynamic URL
const myNewAjaxUrl = /* code to get dynamic url */

// destroy previous select2 instance (may be unnecessary)
// then re-initialize w/overridden config 
$('[data-behavior="select2-parent"]')
  .select2('destroy')
  .select2(Object.assign({}, select2Config, {
    ajax: {
      ...select2Config.ajax,
      url: myNewAjaxUrl,
    },
  );
});
```

You can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41589036/1307183) to see why I call `...select2Config.ajax`, to maintain any other AJAX options you have and to only override the `url` parameter. You could also just do this separately if you thought it looked cleaner:

```
const newConfig = Object.assign({}, select2Config);
newConfig.ajax.url = /* code to get dynamic url */

$('[data-behavior="select2-parent"]').select2('destroy').select2(newConfig);
```

Comment: Did you re-initialize using the same config? Could there be other code interfering?

Comment: Hmm... I need to check this again.  I perhaps had my call BEFORE the `.html()` by mistake.  I can now get the select2 to load but I don't think I can use the config variable as my url is actually built dynamically on other form input values.

Comment: That being said it would still be idea to have the original call persist. I am duplicating code here in two places.

Comment: I will update my answer with a method to do what you need.

Comment: Updated - have a look